# How to successfully add a trigger

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, triggers

I have manually written and added a trigger through PHPMyAdmin, MySQL, to one of my tables whereby upon inserting a new row in the table campaign_categories would perform the following actions:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE `main_campaign_id`       INT;
    DECLARE `inserted_category_id`   INT;
    DECLARE `new_category_row_id`    INT;

    SET `new_category_row_id` =
        (SELECT max(`id`) 
         FROM `campaign_categories`);

    SET `main_campaign_id` = 
        (SELECT `campaign_id` 
        FROM `campaign_categories`
        WHERE `id` = `new_category_row_id`);

    SET `inserted_category_id` = 
        (SELECT `category_id` 
        FROM `campaign_categories`
        WHERE `id` = `new_category_row_id`);


    INSERT INTO `campaign_category_metro_bids`(
         `campaign_id`
        ,`category_id`
        ,`metro_id`)
    SELECT 
         `main_campaign_id` as 'campaign_id'
        ,`main_category_id` as 'category_id'
        ,m.`metro_id`       as 'metro_id'
    FROM `campaign_categories`
    CROSS JOIN `campaign_metros` m
        WHERE m.`campaign_id` = `main_campaign_id`;
END
```

However, upon performing the action in my app that would insert a new row in the table campaign_categories, the app returns the following error message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in CampaignsController#update
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'main_category_id' in 'field list': INSERT INTO `campaign_categories` (`campaign_id`, `category_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (21, 1, '2014-09-28 00:01:40', '2014-09-28 00:01:40')
```

How can I permit rails to allow for this trigger/any trigger in the app?

Comment: did you make sure that column main_category_id is present in database ? i.e. did you run rake db:migrate after adding columns ?

Comment: that's the problem, there are no columns named `main_campaign_id`, in the database. In the trigger above, where there is a DECLARE they are variables and therefore no such table or column is named `main_campaign_id, main_category_id, inserted_category_id`...etc. Should I not use variables but simply sub-selects? Making sure that all columns and tables referenced exist in the db?

Comment: i am sorry ..i dint get your final question ..what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I am asking if rails does not like my trigger because there are variables that appear nowhere else in the db? ie. `inserted_category_id`...etc. Would it be better to simply create the trigger, using only columns and table names that already exist in the database? ie. `campaign_categories` table and `campaign_id` exist in the database. Or does rails just not like triggers from PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: exactly..when you are try to refer a column name ..it would refer the database, if it doesnt find the column you have mentioned..it would throw error. In first place why cant you create trigger in rails way ?

Comment: ok, I tested that and it work. In rails it feels so constricting to  use active record for what I was trying to do. This is a VERY valuable piece that needs complete data integrity. If you want to form/post an answer I can select it correct as your answer provided help to allow exactly what I was trying to accomplish through the method I was trying to accomplish it with. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are try to refer a column name ..it would refer the database for its existence, and if it doesn't find the column you have mentioned..it would throw error you have mentioned in your question. Check for database column existence in database and also make sure that you have migrated `rake db:migrate` once you add your columns.